# Vectorising a for loop where logic spans rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, algorithmic-trading, back-testing

The table below shows an example of a strategy where a signal is generated in `row 2` and then an opposite signal is generated in `row 5`.

```
     row     open_signal     close_signal      live
      1           0               0             0
      2           1               0             1
      3           0               0             1
      4           0               0             1
      5           0               1             0
      6           0               0             0
```

I want to optimise the calculation of the `live` column.

Is there a way to vectorise this problem in either **Pandas** or **Numpy** for improved performance, generating the same result as the for loop example below?

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

example = {'date': [str(datetime(2017,1,1)), str(datetime(2017,1,2)),str(datetime(2017,1,3)),str(datetime(2017,1,4)),str(datetime(2017,1,5)),str(datetime(2017,1,6)),
                    str(datetime(2017,1,7)), str(datetime(2017,1,8)),str(datetime(2017,1,9)), str(datetime(2017,1,10)),str(datetime(2017,1,11)), str(datetime(2017,1,12)),
                    str(datetime(2017,1,13)),str(datetime(2017,1,14))],
           'open':        [142.11, 142.87, 141.87, 142.11, 142.00, 142.41, 142.50, 142.75, 140.87, 141.25, 141.10, 141.15, 142.55, 142.75],
           'close':       [142.87, 141.87, 142.11, 142.00, 142.41, 142.50, 142.75, 140.87, 141.25, 141.10, 141.15, 142.55, 142.75, 142.11],
           'open_signal': [False,  False,  False,  False,  False,  True,  False,  False,  False,  False,  False,  False,  False,  False],
           'close_signal':[False,  False,  False,  False,  False,  False,  False,  False,  False,   True,  False,  False,  False,  False]
           }

data = pd.DataFrame(example)

in_trade = False
for i in data.iterrows():
    if i[1].open_signal:
        in_trade = True
    if i[1].close_signal:
        in_trade = False
    data.loc[i[0],'in_trade'] = in_trade
```

Comment: Is it possible that the open signal may become high multiple times before the closing signal? Similarly is it possible that the close signal becomes high multiple times before the next open signal? If so, the current `cumsum()` approaches below won't work.

Comment: To clarify my example,  yes the open signal may become true multiple times before a close signal occurs. There will also be cases where there is a close signal where there is no prior open signal. Both of these cases would be handled correctly in the for loop example.

Comment: To clarify my example,  yes the open signal may become true multiple times before a close signal occurs. There will also be cases where there is a close signal where there is no prior open signal. Both of these cases would be handled correctly in the for loop example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Simplistic case

For the simplistic case as in the posted sample, here's one vectorized way with NumPy -

```
ar = np.zeros(len(data), dtype=int)
ar[data.open_signal.values] = 1
ar[data.close_signal.values] = -1
data['out'] = ar.cumsum().astype(bool)
```

Runtime test -

Using the sample dataset and scaling it `100000` times along the rows for the testing.

```
In [191]: data = pd.concat([data]*100000,axis=0); data.index = range(len(data))

# @Dark's soln with int output
In [192]: %timeit data['new'] = data['open_signal'].cumsum().ne(data['close_signal'].cumsum()).astype(int)
100 loops, best of 3: 13.4 ms per loop

# @Dark's soln with bool output
In [194]: %timeit data['new'] = data['open_signal'].cumsum().ne(data['close_signal'].cumsum()).astype(bool)
100 loops, best of 3: 10 ms per loop

# Proposed in this post
In [195]: %%timeit
     ...: ar = np.zeros(len(data), dtype=int)
     ...: ar[data.open_signal.values] = 1
     ...: ar[data.close_signal.values] = -1
     ...: data['out'] = ar.cumsum().astype(bool)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.52 ms per loop
```

---

#### Generic case

Now, to solve for a generic case with :

1] A closed signal coming after no prior open signal.

2] Multiple open signals coming prior to the next close signal.

3] Multiple close signals coming prior to the next open signal.

We would need few more steps.

**Approach #1 :** Here's one based upon `searchsorted` -

```
s0 = np.flatnonzero(data.open_signal.values)
s1 = np.flatnonzero(data.close_signal.values)

idx0 = np.searchsorted(s1,s0,'right')
s0c = s0[np.r_[True,idx0[1:] > idx0[:-1]]]

idx1 = np.searchsorted(s0c,s1,'right')
s1c = s1[np.r_[True,idx1[1:] > idx1[:-1]]]

ar = np.zeros(len(data), dtype=int)
ar[s0c] = 1
ar[s1c] = -1
if s1c[0] < s0c[0]:
    ar[s1c[0]] = 0
data['out'] = ar.cumsum().astype(bool)
```

Sample output -

```
In [360]: data
Out[360]: 
    close_signal  open_signal    out
0          False        False  False
1          False        False  False
2           True        False  False
3          False        False  False
4          False        False  False
5          False         True   True
6          False        False   True
7          False         True   True
8          False        False   True
9           True        False  False
10         False        False  False
11          True        False  False
12         False        False  False
13         False        False  False
```

**Approach #2 :** Possibly faster one as we would avoid using `searchsorted` and instead leverage `masking` -

```
mix_arr = data.open_signal.values.astype(int) - data.close_signal.values
ar = np.zeros(len(data), dtype=int)
mix_mask = mix_arr!=0
mix_val = mix_arr[mix_mask]
    
valid_mask = np.r_[True, mix_val[1:] != mix_val[:-1]]
ar[mix_mask] = mix_arr[mix_mask]*valid_mask
if mix_val[0] == -1:
    ar[mix_mask.argmax()] = 0    

data['out'] = ar.cumsum().astype(bool)
```

Comment: Sir you got it.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant edit to handle the more difficult case.

Answer (score 2):

We can compare the cumulative sum i.e

```
data['new'] = data['open_signal'].cumsum().ne(data['close_signal'].cumsum()).astype(int)

  row  open_signal  close_signal  live  new
0    1            0             0     0    0
1    2            1             0     1    1
2    3            0             0     1    1
3    4            0             0     1    1
4    5            0             1     0    0
5    6            0             0     0    0
```